# ScrollViewer around zoom/pan window

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

`ScrollViewer` can automatically add horizontal/vertical scrollbars for a given element. Now, I have an image wrapped inside zooming/panning control. I want to add scrollbars to the view containing this zooming control. When the image is fully visible, the scrollbars should be invisible. When 10% of the image is visible, the scrollbar thumb should occopy 1/10 of the scrollbar (standard behavior).

The problem here is that I want the `ScrollViewer` to occupy the area of the zooming control, and adapt its values using the image *inside* this control. Perhaps this can be done using some kind of binding to the child of the zooming control? Or maybe using two `ScrollBar` instances instead?

```
Zoomed out
+----------------+
|                |
|   +-------+    |
|   | image |    |
|   +-------+    |
|                |
+----------------+

Zoomed in
+----------------+
|                |
|  image         sc <- adapting to visibleHeight/imageHeight
|                ro
|                ll
|                |
+---- scroll ----+  <- adapting to visibleWidth/imageWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. Solved it using a `ScrollViewer`. I had to set the `CanContentScroll` to `True`...